# IF AND Statement not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to Return a value based on 1)Month of the Year and 2) Hour of the day. My IF statement for the summer works however the Winter Formula is not working.

Summer:    `=IF(WEEKDAY(B3,2)>5,Input!$F$7,IF(COUNTIF(HOLIDAYS,DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)))>0,Input!$F$7,IF(AND(MONTH(B3)>=Input!$B$6,MONTH(B3)<=Input!$B$7,HOUR(B3)+1>=Input!$B$8,HOUR(B3)+1<=Input!$B$9),Input!$F$6,Input!$F$7)))`

Winter:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B3,2)>5,Input!$F$7,IF(COUNTIF(HOLIDAYS,DATE(YEAR(B3),MONTH(B3),DAY(B3)))>0,Input!$F$7,IF(AND(MONTH(B3)>=Input!$D$6,MONTH(B3)<=Input!$D$7,HOUR(B3)+1>=Input!$D$8,HOUR(B3)+1<=Input!$D$9),Input!$F$6,Input!$F$7)))
```

As you can see these formulas are extremely similar, yet the second is not working. I tend to think the AND statement is wrong.

The Range of the months and hours for the winter is October to March, hence greater than or equal to 10 and less than or equal to 3. The hours are HE7-HE11 (HE-hour ending).

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!
Z

Comment: Just based on your logic, a number can't be >= 10 AND <= 3. Sounds like you need an OR condition.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: You could simplify both formulas by using NETWORKDAYS to check for both weekends and holidays, e.g. for summer `=IF(AND(NETWORKDAYS(B3,B3)=1,MONTH(B3)>=Input!$B$6,MONTH(B3)<=Input!$B$7,HOUR(B3)+1>=Input!$B$8,HOUR(B3)+1<=Input!$B$9),Input!$F$6,Input!$F$7)`